# Comparable Speed of iPhone 4s Processor

Tags: iphone, ios

Developing an algorithm that will eventually make its way into an iPhone app. Right now on my 3.4GHz quad core, 8 thread intel processor, the algo takes about 3 seconds. Any way to parlay these numbers to iPhone 4s specs? I've read the processer is 1GHz, but my sense is there is not an apples to apples linear comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you could divide by 32*3.4 it still would be apples to oranges.  The iPad uses an ARM processor that has a very different architecture to your intel processor, as well as running on a completely different OS, using different process management techniques.  I'm afraid the only way is to just run it on a real device and profile it.

Comment: OK then, thought that might be the case. Next stop: C# to Obj C conversion. Thank you.

Comment: @Mickey have fun on the trip.

Comment: I'd like to see Objective-C# :)  C# with the Objective-C object model :)